# Using ClickOnce Environment Variables in .NET 6 for programmatic updates

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I'm trying to set up ClickOnce in VS2022 using .NET 7 for a WPF application so that we can deploy updates to a shared file location allowing users across the business to download updates from a central location. I want to allow these updates to be handled programmatically, and from what I can see, ClickOnce no longer works the same past .NET 5

It seems that instead of being able to use the System.Deployment class, we now need to use Environment Variables.

Has anyone here had experience with this? I've tried to use the Environment Variables, but they all appear to be returning null. Do I need to manually set them myself? I was under the impression that they would be populated on launch from the manifest - is this not the case?

I'm currently trying to read the Environment Variables from the App.xaml.cs OnStartup override method, but each variable is coming back null. I've even tried publishing and launching the application to see if the variables are populated when running outside of VS, but no such luck.

Any help massively appreciated! Documentation, ChatGPT and CoPilot have failed me so far